# How to integrate Push Notification to an already existing app?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I already have an app in AppStore, now I need to integrate Push Notification to it in the next version. Do I need to generate new certificates for it or can modify the existing certificates used for code signing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to add push-notification in your application then you need enable push-notification, also need to generate certificate at Apple Developer portal and install it. (which will not affect on current live app).

Then add code to register push notification, (Also can use delegates as required)

```
 -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound);
}
```

And finally you need to upload **new version of application.**

Comment: Thanks Dhaval. Also will the change in certificate affect people updating the app?

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the application certificate and therefore also the distribution certificate. An update of both is OK